# issues with responsive side bar with scrollable main

Tags: css, layout

I have these samples:

```
`https://codepen.io/deleite/pen/ExyxaJr`
```

What I am trying to achieve is the same as here:

```
`https://codepen.io/deleite/pen/QWEWwXO`
```

But the second one is using gap prop the first one needs a wrapper to have the gutter.

Any ideas how I can keep the one with the margin gutter trick but making the main scrollable when the side bar is next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out so if anyone need similar solution this codepen works in IE as well.

The only downside here is that I am using media query instead of the holy albatross but that is not need for my use case right now.

```
[sidebar with scrollable main IE 11 compatible][1]
[1]: https://codepen.io/deleite/pen/NWrWMWP
```